# I want to write a function that takes an integr and returns a list of all of its multiplicators

Tags: python

for example 
input : 20
output : [[1,20], [2,10], [4,5]]

I have tried this, but some how i cant get it to work correctly

```
def Multiplicators(n):
    w=2
    while 1:
        if w*n-1==n:
            print w,n
            n-=1
        elif n==0:
            break
        else:
            n-=1

Multiplicators(20)
```

Comment: You have two problems: the algorithm itself looks wrong, and you are printing instead of building a list to return.

Comment: What you call "multiplicator" is commonly known as [divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor).

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution working in Python 2.x and 3.x

```
def Multiplicators(n):
    return [[i,n/i] for i in range(n+1) if i and n%i is 0 and i <= n/i]

print (Multiplicators(20))
```

output will be [[1, 20], [2, 10], [4, 5]]
 as requested

Comment: Don't rely on low integers being cached, use `==`.

Comment: thanks, changed it, tho i doubt it would have given any problems

Comment: `for i,j in enumerate(range(n))` – `i` and `j` will always be the same in this case, you can just omit `enumerate` and use `i` where `j` is used.

Comment: yes, you're right. did not spend much time on that. some may want to use the step width with range, so then it would be useful. But yes, you're correct

Comment: Edit to the reflect the exact expectations of the questions incl. suggestions in comments

Answer (score 1):

@EvilSmurf has correctely pointed out that my answer doens't work in Python 2. Please note that the method suggested in this answer will only work in Python 3. You may make a few alterations to make it work in Python 2. *The proof is left as an exercise to the reader* :)

---

I'm going to propose two diferent solution that work in the same way. The first is more similar to your original answer. The second uses Python's "list comprehension".

```
def Multiplicators(n):
    multiples = []
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        div = n / i
        if div % 1 == 0:
            multiples.append([i, int(div)])
    return multiples


def Multiplicators_list_comprehension(n):
    return [[i, int(n / i)] for i in range(1, n + 1) if n / i % 1 == 0]


print(Multiplicators(20))
print(Multiplicators_list_comprehension(20))
```

The output, for both, willl be:

```
[[1, 20], [2, 10], [4, 5], [5, 4], [10, 2], [20, 1]]
```

#### Explanation

- In `for i in range(1, n + 1)` we are iterating trough all possible integer multiples of `n`.
- If `n / i` is an whole number i.e. `(n / i) % 1 == 0`, we have found a multiple!
- Now we just need to append the result, `[i, int(div)]`, to our list. But we convert `div` to an `int` to get rid of the trailing zero.

To learn about list comprehension look here:

- [Official docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

---

#### Alternative

To match the result asked in the question, you will have to change `if div % 1 == 0` to `if div % 1 == 0 and i <= n / i`. This way, your output will be

```
[[1, 20], [2, 10], [4, 5]]
```

instead of

```
[[1, 20], [2, 10], [4, 5], [5, 4], [10, 2], [20, 1]]
```

Comment: the output for both is [[1, 20], [2, 10], [3, 6], [4, 5], [5, 4], [6, 3], [7, 2], [8, 2], [9, 2], [10, 2], [11, 1], [12, 1], [13, 1], [14, 1], [15, 1], [16, 1], [17, 1], [18, 1], [19, 1]]
[[1, 20], [2, 10], [3, 6], [4, 5], [5, 4], [6, 3], [7, 2], [8, 2], [9, 2], [10, 2], [11, 1], [12, 1], [13, 1], [14, 1], [15, 1], [16, 1], [17, 1], [18, 1], [19, 1]] - check your implementation

Comment: @EvilSmurf I'm using Python 3, so it works as stated in the answer. I will put a disclaimer about which version I'm using. Do the same in your answer. Thank you for the heads up!

Comment: it does...strange that the behavior is so different

Answer (score -2):

You can simply use list comprehension to solve it:

```
 a = 20
 b = [[i,a//i] for i in range(1,a) if a%i == 0 and a!=1]
```

Which is same as:

```
a = 20
b = []  # creating empty list
for i in range(1,a): # iterate over range (LOWER_BOUND, UPPER_BOUND)
    if a != 1 and a%i == 0:
        b.append([i, a//i]) # append data to list

print(b)



output is : [[1, 20], [2, 10], [4, 5], [5, 4], [10, 2]]
```

Comment: Okay. Then, we can check condition for ```1``` as above. I have already made the changes by the way.

Comment: I think you don't really got my point. 1 is a valid positive number which divides by 1. So 1 needs to work. To just take this out is NOT A SOLUTION ;) - look at my solution above

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps what you meant was finding factors of a numbers right? below code is what you are looking for?

```
   def Multiplicators(n):
      for i in range(n):
         if (i!=0 and n%i == 0):
            print (int(n/i),i)

   Multiplicators(100)
```

Comment: this would also give you None as last multiplicator, pls check your implementation

Comment: after correcting this is my output,

`========================= RESTART: C:\programs\1.py =========================
100 1
50 2
25 4
20 5
10 10
5 20
4 25
2 50
>>>`